# Put/get byte array value using JSONObject

Tags: java, arrays, pdf, jersey

I tried to get my `byte[]` value from `JSONObject` using following code but I am not getting original `byte[]` value.

```
JSONArray jSONArray = jSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONConstant.BYTE_ARRAY_LIST);
    int len = jSONArray.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        byte[] b = jSONArray.get(i).toString().getBytes();
       //Following line creates pdf file of this byte arry "b"
        FileCreator.createPDF(b, "test PDF From Web Resource.pdf");

    }
}
```

Above code creates pdf file but file can not open i.e corrupted file. But, when I use same class and method to create file:

```
FileCreator.createPDF(b, "test PDF From Web Resource.pdf");
```

before adding into `JSONObject` like follwoing:

```
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
jSONObject.put(JSONConstant.BYTE_ARRAY_LIST, bList);
```

it creates file i.e I can open pdf file and read its content.

*What I did wrong to get `byte[]` from `JSONObject` so that it is creating corrupted file? Please kindly guide me. And I always welcome to comments. Thank You.*

Comment: Does your jsonarray contain multiple PDF documents stored as byte[]?

Comment: Yes, it may contain multiple PDF documents. But right now for testing I am adding only one PDF document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue with the help of *apache commons* library. First I added the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

The technique that I was using previously was wrong for me *(Not sure for other)*. Following is the solution how I solved my problem.

*Solution:*

*I added byte array value previously on JSONObject and stored as String. When I tried to get from JSONObject to my byte array it returned String not my original byte array. And did not get the original byte array even I use following:*

```
byte[] bArray=jSONObject.getString(key).toString().getBytes();
```

Now,

First I encoded my byte array into string and kept on JSONObject. See below:

```
byte[] bArray=(myByteArray);
//Following is the code that encoded my byte array and kept on String
String encodedString = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(bArray);
jSONObject.put(JSONConstant.BYTE_ARRAY_LIST , encodedString);
```

*And the code from which I get back my original byte array:*

```
String getBackEncodedString = jSONObject.getString(JSONConstant.BYTE_ARRAY_LIST);
//Following code decodes to encodedString and returns original byte array
byte[] backByte = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(getBackEncodedString);
//Creating pdf file of this backByte
FileCreator.createPDF(backByte, "fileAfterJSONObject.pdf");
```

That's it.

Answer (score 4):

This might be of help for those using Java 8. Make use of `java.util.Base64`.

Encoding byte array to String :

```
String encodedString = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
JSONObject.put("encodedString",encodedString);
```

Decode byte array from String :

```
String encodedString = (String) JSONObject.get("encodedString");
byte[] byteArray = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

For tests example(com.fasterxml.jackson used):

```
        byte[] bytes = "pdf_report".getBytes("UTF-8");
        Mockito.when(reportService.createPackageInvoice(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(bytes);
        String jStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bytes).replaceAll("\\\"", ""); // return string with a '\"' escape...
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/getReport").param("someparam", "222"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                ...
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", is(jStr)))
        ;
```

Answer (score -2):

When inserting a byte array into a JSONObject the toString() method is invoked.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    byte[] b = "hello".getBytes();
    o.put("A", b);
    System.out.println(o.get("A"));
}
```

Example output:

```
[B@1bd8c6e
```

so you have to store it in a way that you can parse the String into the original datatype.